# Finding Max Value Across Three Columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr, max

I want to find the maximum value in each row across three columns and have the new column print the name of the highest value column.

An example table would appear as follows:

```
x = c(1,2,5,4,5 ) 
y = c(2,3,3,1,1 )
z = c(4,4,2,1,1 )
df<-data.frame(x,y,z)
```

I want to create this:

| id | x | y | z | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 4 | z |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 4 | z |
| 3 | 5 | 3 | 2 | x |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 1 | x |
| 5 | 5 | 1 | 1 | x |

I tried:

```
df%>% rowwise() %>% mutate(max = max(x, y, z))
```

And received the output:

| id | x | y | z | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 4 |
| 3 | 5 | 3 | 2 | 5 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 | 1 | 4 |
| 5 | 5 | 1 | 1 | 5 |

Does anybody know how I can correct this code to yield the desired outcome?

Answer (score 6):

Use `pmax` instead of `max` as it vectorized and doesn't need to go through `rowwise` (which should be very slow)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(Max = pmax(x, y, z))
```

---

In the OP's function with `rowwise`, if we need the column name, use `which.max` to get the column index

```
df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(Max = names(.)[which.max(c(x, y, z))]) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 4
      x     y     z Max  
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
1     1     2     4 z    
2     2     3     4 z    
3     5     3     2 x    
4     4     1     1 x    
5     5     1     1 x
```

---

Or use vectorizeid `max.col` to find the column index of each row with the max value and get the `names` corresponding to that index

```
df %>% 
    mutate(Max = names(.)[max.col(., 'first')])
```

-output

```
  x y z Max
1 1 2 4   z
2 2 3 4   z
3 5 3 2   x
4 4 1 1   x
5 5 1 1   x
```