# Find the name of the maximum value by row by range of columns in R

Tags: r, max, multiple-columns

I have a similar problem as outlined [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69487693/finding-max-value-across-three-columns-in-r). The problem is that I have more than 200 columns, so I can't list them all as in this code:

```
  df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(Max = names(.)[which.max(c(x, y, z))]) %>%
  ungroup
```

I have tried using this code but it is giving the max of all my columns and I just need the max of columns 3 to 223. Columns 1 and 2 are ID and year and I need them.

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Max = names(.)[which.max(c_across(3:223))]) %>%
  ungroup()
```

All my columns have different names so I can't use

```
mutate(Max = names(.)[which.max(c_across(starts_with("X")))])
```

How can I find the name of the column with the maximum value per row of a dataset with around 200 columns without listing all of the 200 columns' names?

Comment: `transform(df, Max = names(df)[max.col(df)])` should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second approach is on the right track, you just need to subset `names(.)` as well:

```r
set.seed(13)
library(dplyr)

# example data
df <- data.frame(id = 1:5, year = 2020:2024)
for (L in LETTERS[1:5]) df[[L]] <- sample(5)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Max = names(.[3:7])[which.max(c_across(3:7))]) %>%
  ungroup()
```

But faster and more succinct to use `max.col()`:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(Max = names(.[3:7])[max.col(.[3:7], "first")])
```

Result:

```r
  id year A B C D E Max
1  1 2020 3 4 3 5 5   D
2  2 2021 4 5 1 4 3   B
3  3 2022 1 1 2 1 1   C
4  4 2023 2 2 4 2 2   C
5  5 2024 5 3 5 3 4   A
```

Answer (score 3):

In base R, use `max.col`:

```
cbind(df, Max = names(df)[max.col(df)])
```

Comment: It is not working, also, I need a range from within the dataset, column 3 to 223

Comment: @Lilia you will have to provide dataset. ie `names(df)[3:223][max.col(df[3:223])]` should give you the names. or just `names(df)[max.col(df[3:223]) + 2]`

Comment: It gives me a list of characters, but I need them to be identified by the ID and year that are my first two columns. That's why I'm trying to add the name as an extra column to the dataset.

Comment: @Lilia you just cbind those characters into the dataframe ie `cbind(df, Max = names(df)[3:223][max.col(df[3:223])])` .This returns what you desire